# Salesforce User unable to run on click javascript button but administrator can

Tags: apex, javascript

Hello guys I have a button that is suppose to allow the user clicking it to take ownership of a record. When I run it as admin, all else works but as a standard user nothing happens:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}

var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, id__c FROM Job_Requisition__c WHERE id__c = '{!Job_Requisition__c.id__c}'");
var records = query.getArray("records");
var jobRequisition = records[0];

if ("{!Job_Requisition__c.owned__c}" == false) {
    jobRequisition.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    jobRequisition.owned__c = true;

    result = sforce.connection.update([jobRequisition]);
    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {

    //Create tasks
    var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
    task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    task.Subject = '1 - Review Data Quality';
    task.ActivityDate = new Date();
    task.WhatId = jobRequisition.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([task]);

    var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
    task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    task.Subject = '2 - Engage with Recruiter';
    task.ActivityDate = new Date();
    task.WhatId = jobRequisition.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([task]);

    var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
    task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    task.Subject = '3 - Update Must Haves';
    task.ActivityDate = new Date();
    task.WhatId = jobRequisition.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([task]);

    var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
    task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    task.Subject = '4 - Confirm Priority Listing Ratio';
    task.ActivityDate = new Date();
    task.WhatId = jobRequisition.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([task]);

    var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
    task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    task.Subject = '5 - Create Chatter Group';
    task.ActivityDate = new Date();
    task.WhatId = jobRequisition.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([task]);

    var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
    task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
    task.Subject = '6 - Select CSS';
    task.ActivityDate = new Date();
    task.WhatId = jobRequisition.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([task]);
alert('Tasks created');

    //Create chatter group and add Job Requisition to group
    var myGroup = new sforce.SObject("CollaborationGroup");
    myGroup.Name = "{!Job_Requisition__c.Name}";
    myGroup.CollaborationType = 'Private';                   
    result = sforce.connection.create([myGroup]);

    var groupRecord = new sforce.SObject("CollaborationGroupRecord");
    groupRecord.recordId = jobRequisition.Id;

    var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = '{!Job_Requisition__c.Name}'");
    var records = query.getArray("records");
    var myGroup = records[0];

    groupRecord.CollaborationGroupId = myGroup.Id;
    result = sforce.connection.create([groupRecord]);

    var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, id__c FROM Job_Requisition__c WHERE id__c = '{!Job_Requisition__c.id__c}'");
    var records = query.getArray("records");
    var jobRequisition = records[0];

    jobRequisition.createChatterGroup__c = true;
    result = sforce.connection.update([jobRequisition]);

    alert('You are now the Job Requisition owner');
    }
    window.location.reload();
} else {
    //Assign CSS as Job Requisition owner
    if ("{!Job_Requisition__c.worked__c}" == false && "{!Job_Requisition__c.status__c}" != 'Assigned' && "{!Job_Requisition__c.owned__c}" == true && "{!Job_Requisition__c.checkedJobRequisitionTasks__c}" == true && "{!Job_Requisition__c.updatedJobRequisitionTasks__c}" == true) {
        var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, id__c FROM Job_Requisition__c WHERE id__c = '{!Job_Requisition__c.id__c}'");
        var records = query.getArray("records");
        var jobRequisition = records[0];

        jobRequisition.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
        jobRequisition.worked__c = true;
        jobRequisition.status__c = 'Assigned';
        result = sforce.connection.update([jobRequisition]);

        //Create CSS request to join existing collaboration group
        var groupMemberRequest = new sforce.SObject("CollaborationGroupMemberRequest");
        groupMemberRequest.RequesterId = "{!$User.Id}";

        var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = '{!Job_Requisition__c.Name}'");
        var records = query.getArray("records");
        var myGroup = records[0];

        groupMemberRequest.CollaborationGroupId = myGroup.Id;
        result = sforce.connection.create([groupMemberRequest]);
        alert(result);

        alert('You are now working this Job Requisition');
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        alert('Job Requisition is already owned');
    }
}
```

What permission do I have to change on the profile to allow them to run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change ownership of a record, you need Transfer Record permissions (which is basically Full Access in most cases). In other words, your button, running in the security context of the user, can't transfer the record unless the user already had such permission. Your button "does nothing" because it's crashing when you try to update the record's ownership. You can either (a) give the users Modify All Data, or (b) use a "without sharing" Apex class to transfer ownership. Basically, that might look like this:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js")}
var result = sforce.apex.execute("JobReqWS", "takeOwnership", { ownerId: "{!$User.Id}", recordId: "{!Job_Requisition__c.Id}" });
if(result) {
    alert(result);
}
window.top.location.reload();
```

The actual function would look like this:

```
global without sharing class JobReqWS {
    webservice static String takeOwnership(Id recordId, Id ownerId) {
        try {
            Job_Requisition__c req = [SELECT Owned__c FROM Job_Requisition__c WHERE Id = :recordId FOR UPDATE];
            if(req.Owned__c) {
                return 'Record already has ownership.';
            }
            req.OwnerId = ownerId;
            update req;
            // Create the tasks now
        } catch(QueryException e) {
            return 'Invalid ID specified';
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            return 'Error while trying to operate on records:' + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, if you're going to just give the users permission, you *should update your button logic*. You're burning through quite a few API calls by not updating records in bulk. You should be doing something like this:

```
var tasks = [], task;
task = new sforce.SObject('Task');
// populate fields, then...
tasks.push(task);
task = new sforceSObject('Task');
// repeat as needed, then...
sforce.connection.create(tasks);
```

Not only will you save on API calls, you'll drastically reduce the time needed for the user to get a result back. However, even that isn't as great of an idea as simply creating a web service and calling it directly.

Comment: Thank you very much @sfdcfox, this really helped...now my button is working